# Project Euler N2 - Fibonacci algorithm isnt working properly

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

> Each new term in the Fibonacci
>   sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1
>   and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> Find the sum of all the even-valued
>   terms in the sequence which do not
>   exceed four million.

```
        Int64[] Numeros = new Int64[4000005];
        Numeros[0] = 1;
        Numeros[1] = 2;

        Int64 Indice = 2;
        Int64 Acumulador = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
        {
            Numeros[Indice] = Numeros[Indice - 2] + Numeros[Indice - 1];

            if (Numeros[Indice] % 2 == 0)
            {
                if ((Numeros[Indice] + Acumulador) > 4000000)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Acumulador += Numeros[Indice];
                }
            }

            Indice++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Acumulador);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

My program isn't functioning as it should be I guess because on Project Euler they say my answer is incorrect. Maybe I'm overlooking something. Any help?

Comment: For a start, you only need to keep track of the last two numbers.

Comment: Do first a check on the upper limit before checking if the number is even.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
if ((Numeros[Indice] + Acumulador) > 4000000)
```

is checking for the sum being greater than 4MM.  You need to check that the term (Numeros[Indice]) is greater than 4MM.  So changing that to this...

```
if (Numeros[Indice] > 4000000)
```

is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

And also man your test condition in for loop is useless.. `i` wil never reach the value of 4000000.
simply a

```
while(1){
//code
}
```

will also do, no need of `i` as u never use it